# Help getting the values from user profile fields from currently logged in user

Tags: users, 8

As the title says, I am trying to get the values from a custom field I added to the user profile. I am using this code from a previously asked question regarding this.

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$value = user->custom_field->value;
```

This seemed to work for the person that previously asked this question but the problem I am running into is that it is only returning values of an anonymous user regardless of who I am logged in as. For example if I replace custom_field with uid it will return a value of '0'. Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Install Devel module, and write dsm($user); above the code you have already, then reload the page, click on the yellow bar, and tell us what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a $ in your second line.. Should be $user->

I always use the below.

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid)
```

And then get the field like your last line. If someone else could confirm if that is a waste and there's a better way to load the field, that'd be great.

Comment: I think its a typo by @jecunningham2281.